# How to fix expired token in AWS s3 copy command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-sts

I need to run the command `aws s3 cp <filename> <bucketname>` from an EC2 RHEL instance to copy a file from the instance to an S3 bucket.

When I run this command, I receive this error: `An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired`

I also found that this same error occurs when trying to run many other CLI commands from the instance.

I do not want to change my IAM role because the command was previously working perfectly fine and IAM policy changes must go through an approval process. I have double checked the IAM role the instance is assuming and it still contains the correct configuration for allowing PutObject on the correct resources.

What can I do to allow AWS CLI commands to work again in my instance?

Comment: What is the output of `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/`?

Answer (score 0):

AWS API tokens are time-sensitive, and VMs in the cloud tend to suffer from clock drift.

Check that time is accurate on the RHEL instance, and use **ntp** servers to make sure any drift is regularly corrected.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I double checked the date and it appears to be accurate.